# Trying to get property 'comments' of non-object (View: /Applications/AMPPS/www/zenit/resources/views/middleware.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I try to get comments belonging to project, a special user has posted but get this error:

> Trying to get property 'comments' of non-object (View: /Applications/AMPPS/www/zenit/resources/views/middleware.blade.php)

I created a foreach loop in middleware.blade.php as follows;

```
@foreach(Auth::user()->courses->comments as $comment)
```

In My Course model I created the hasManyThrough relationship as follows

```
public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Comment::class, Project::class, 'course_id', 'project_id', 'id', 'id');
}
```

My projects table has a course_id column, and my comments table has a project_id column

Is there anyone who could help me? Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you get when you dump `Auth::user()->courses`?

Comment: when I dump Auth::user()->courses I get null

Comment: Well, there you have it. Check how your User class is hydrated - there aren't any courses in there.

Comment: It also feels that due to the formulation: `->courses->comments`, courses should be a collection, so it wouldn't be possible to get comments like that.

Comment: Please add relevant code by editing the question, not in the comments. If that is a function, then you should call it like this: `->courses()`. Calling `->courses` is looking for a public property.

Comment: Ok, thanks, El_Vanja I try

Answer (score 0):

First it'll be better if you give your belongsTo relation a singular name not plural, because it retrieves only 1 object:

```
public function course()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Course::class);
}
```

And also in some cases `$user->course` can be null, so it won't have comments, so just check that case before foreach loop

```
// in some blade template
@if(auth()->user()->course)
    @foreach(auth()->user()->course->comments as $comment)
        {{ $comment->id }}
    @endforeach
@endif
```